# abstract algebra permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am dealing with a permutation in the form:
$a=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 \\
  3 &1 &4 &5 &6 &2
\end{pmatrix}$
I am asked to find $|< a >|$ and $a^{100}$. I don't really understand how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: These questions were on Page 83 of A First Course In Abstract Algebra, by John B. Fraleigh. I don't know what functions the brackets | | or < > are meant to perform.

Comment: What does |<a>| mean?

Comment: Hint: Disjoint cycles commute.

Answer (score 0):

Decompose $a$ as a product of disjoint cycles: you should find find$$a=(1\,5)(2\,4\,6\,3)$$
Hence the order of $a$ is the l.c.m. of the orders of cycles components, i.e. the l.c.m. of the lengths of the cycles.

Comment: So what you're saying is, $|<a>|$=4 ?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX!  Yes, exactly.